# AmCharts Gantt Chart with Data time not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to plot out a Gantt chart with Date/Time on the X axis, the code I have is something like this:

```
 AmCharts.useUTC = true;
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "user-pages", {
      "type": "gantt",
      "theme": "light",
      "marginRight": 70,
      "dataDateFormat": "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN",
      "columnWidth": 0.5,
      "valueAxis": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "brightnessStep": 7,
      "graph": {
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "lineAlpha": 1,
        "lineColor": "#fff",
        "balloonText": "<b>[[task]]</b>:<br />[[open]] -- [[value]]"
      },
      "rotate": true,
      "categoryField": "category",
      "segmentsField": "segments",
      "colorField": "color",
      "startDateField": "start",
      "endDateField": "end",
      "dataProvider": [ {
        "category": "Module #1",
        "segments": [ {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T09:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-04T10:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "color": "#b9783f",
          "task": "Gathering requirements"
        }]
      }, {
        "category": "Module #2",
        "segments": [ {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T07:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T08:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "color": "#b9783f",
          "task": "Gathering requirements"
        }, {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T13:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T14:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "task": "Producing specifications"
        }, {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T15:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T16:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "task": "Development"
        } ]
      }, {
        "category": "Module #3",
        "segments": [ {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T09:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T10:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "color": "#b9783f",
          "task": "Gathering requirements"
        }, {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T11:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T12:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "task": "Producing specifications"
        }, {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T15:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T17:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "task": "Development"
        } ]
      }, {
        "category": "Module #4",
        "segments": [ {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T07:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T08:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "color": "#b9783f",
          "task": "Gathering requirements"
        }, {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T13:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T14:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "task": "Producing specifications"
        }, {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T15:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T16:00:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "task": "Development"
        } ]
      }, {
        "category": "Module #5",
        "segments": [ {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T09:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T10:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "color": "#b9783f",
          "task": "Gathering requirements"
        }, {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T11:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T12:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "task": "Producing specifications"
        }, {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T15:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T17:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "task": "Development"
        } ]
      } ],
      "valueScrollbar": {
        "autoGridCount": true
      },
      "chartCursor": {
        "cursorColor": "#55bb76",
        "valueBalloonsEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "valueLineAlpha": 0.5,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "zoomable": false,
        "valueZoomable": true
      },
      "export": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    } );
```

You can see the issue here:
http://jsfiddle.net/28305m8g/1/

If I change the segment of the first one to be in the same date:

```
[ {
        "category": "Module #1",
        "segments": [ {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T09:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-04T10:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "color": "#b9783f",
          "task": "Gathering requirements"
        }]
```

To:

```
[ {
        "category": "Module #1",
        "segments": [ {
          "start": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T09:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "end": AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T10:33:00+00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN"),
          "color": "#b9783f",
          "task": "Gathering requirements"
        }]
```

You can see it works below:
http://jsfiddle.net/28305m8g/2/

Does anyone know why this happens and can help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `AmCharts.stringToDate` incorrectly. The second parameter is the format of the string date the function is trying to parse in the first parameter. Your dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format, not DD-MM-YYYY. Once you fix the format, the chart will render correctly. Ex: `AmCharts.stringToDate("2016-10-03T09:33:00+00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN")`

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/28305m8g/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot xorspark that solution worked, I have a quick question for you, my chart on hovering it now gives me the following error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: g.fixPrevious is not a functionshowGraphBalloon @ amcharts.js:211handleRollOver @ amcharts.js:204(anonymous function) @ amcharts.js:203
browser_adapter.js:93 EXCEPTION: TypeError: g.fixPrevious is not a function`

Do you know what causes this?

Comment: Can't say for sure without a fiddle that reproduces it. The only other time I've seen a similar issue pop up is if you include both amcharts and ammap js files at the same time. If you have both charts and maps on the same page, you should use ammap_amcharts_extension.js instead of ammap.js

Comment: I am using both of ammap.js and amcharts on the same page yes, but once I use ammap_amcharts_extensions.js instead of ammap.js I Then run into the following error:

`amcharts.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
a.inherits.b.fire @ amcharts.js:3
handleReleaseOutside @ ammap_amcharts_extension.js:19
d.handleMouseUp @ amcharts.js:6`

Comment: Fixed, it had to do with me calling export.min.js after ammap_amcharts_extension.js once I changed it to be imported before it, it started working. Thanks once again!